# return wday, day, mon. and yr using javascript dateformat in a browser window

Tags: node.js

```
var today = new Date();

var dateOptions = {
    weekday:"long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric"
  };
 var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", dateOptions);
```

returns empty window, shows nothing at all

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a look at [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your code only creates and initializes 3 variables, you're not logging anything in your console. Also please make sure to format your code and write an understandable title and body.

Answer (score 0):

what do u mean?
u can use

```js
var date = new Date().toUTCString()
var hour = new Date().getUTCHours()
var day = new Date().getUTCDate()
var month = new Date().getUTCMonth()
var year = new Date().getUTCFullYear()
var mstime = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()
console.log(date)
console.log(hour)
console.log(day)
console.log(month)
console.log(year)
console.log(mstime)
//! expected output
Date : Sun, 23 Oct 2022 17:49:20 GMT
Hour : 17
Day : 23
Month : 9
Year : 2022
Get a time but in ms : 1666547360034
```

Comment: const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req,res){

  var today = new Date();
  var options = {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year:"numeric"


  };
 var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);


res.render("List", {
  kindOfDay: day
});

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
actually am building "To Do List" app, so when i test this code with browser window, it returns blank window.

Comment: actually idk but ure write a correct code for a formatted date, but u can try to use moment package theit was same as toLocaleDateString but itll more help u ig

Comment: @Isaac you need to post enough code in your actual question, not in comments to answers. The fact you are using Express is not mentioned nor it it tagged. Please update your question with enough information *and code* for someone to be able to help.